# How to deploy Angular-Flask-MySQL Project on Heroku which Stored in Github repo

Tags: mysql, angular, flask, heroku, cleardb

I am currently working on a project that uses **Angular** as frontend framework, **Flask** as backend framework and **MySQL** as database.
Furthermore, the developement of the application is completed and the source code is stored in private **Github repo**.

My next step is to **deploy** this project on **heroku** server. After done some research l found that i have to change the database to **Clear DB** which is the database available in heroku. As a newbie this is my first web app deployment to heroku server.

Is there any online source where i can refer that can fullfiill my requirement or if somebody has done this approach previousely could please list down the steps so i can follow them. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Check out https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-git  They dont appear to have Angular but that should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks @MattJamison for quick response. I will check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had done a project related to angular and flask. I faced the same issue when it comes to app deployment phase.

I deployed the angular app and the flask app in two separate heroku servers. Using this method it is easy for you to do the furthure developments of the application as well.

Following are some reliable sources you can refer,

Deploy flask app to heroku
https://stackabuse.com/deploying-a-flask-application-to-heroku/

Deploy angular app to heroku
https://www.javaguides.net/2020/11/how-to-deploy-angular-application-to-heroku.html?m=1

After deploy both these frameworks separately you can replace your angular api call from https://localhost:5000/api/ to https://yourbackendserver.herokuapp.com/api/

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Are you aware of any other methods which i can deploy the both frontend and backend in the same Heroku server